# Remove UIActivityIndicator from cell content view when returning from detail view

Tags: uitableview, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a UITableView that gets data from the internet when a cell is clicked it displays the UIActivity Indicator and then pushes to a Detail View controller. When I click back the UITableView cell that I clicked on has a grey background and the cell content is no longer there.

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

{
      static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TableCell";
   TabelCell*cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

```
_activityIndicatorCell = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];

// Get center of cell (vertically)
int center = [cell frame].size.height / 2;

int width = [cell frame].size.width / 1.1;

// Locate spinner in the center of the cell at end of text
[ _activityIndicatorCell  setFrame:CGRectMake(width ,center - 9, 16, 16)];

[_activityIndicatorCell setHidden:YES];
[[cell contentView] addSubview:_activityIndicatorCell];


[  _activityIndicatorCell startAnimating];


[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:YES];
```

}

I then added this code to remove the UIActivityIndicator but its still has a grey box around the cell I clicked on and my UILabel content is no longer there.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {


[  _activityIndicatorCell stopAnimating];
[  _activityIndicatorCell hidesWhenStopped];

[self retrieveData];
}
```

I also reload the tableview in the retrieveData method.

Any ideas why this isn't working ?

If I add the cell data in from  "numberOfRowsInSection" method it works but is this correct?

Also the cell remains grey and does not deselect even though I run:

```
[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

adding this in to the did select method resolved the issue:

```
[cell setSelected:NO animated:YES];
```